# Plugin for visitors to edit content without logging in?

Tags: plugins, posts, editor, content, forms

I have a company catalog and want visitors to edit the information without logging in. I have tried [TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) and it almost worked, too many bugs.

Is there any other good plugin for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have hands-on experience with such use case, but my first suggestion would be to heck out [plugins tagged wiki](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/wiki) in official repository.

Comment: I was going to suggest wiki-like functionality, too.